# Java process with sudo not coming under created cgroup

Tags: java, cgroups

I have a service which runs a Java process. I am assigning cgroup to the service via a slice being added in the systemd unit file. Every command that is run in the run.sh including cat commands come under the cgroup, however the main command to run the java process which has sudo su - op -c Java jar  is still coming up under the default user slice cgroup. What is happening there? Why is cgroup not being reassigned